# Weird Monospace font after 18.10 Update

Tags: fonts, 18.10, atom, adobe-brackets

I updated to Ubuntu 18.10 earlier today. The installation worked without any problems. So far everything seems to be working as expected.

For some reason however, after opening both [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) and [Atom](https://atom.io/), I noticed that a lot of their fonts have been inexplicably changed to a monospaced font that is quite hard to read.

- I tried changing my system fonts with Gnome Tweaks.
- I tried switching back to the default Ubuntu theme.
- I tried uninstalling and reinstalling
- I tried changing the font settings from the programs themselves (they had no option to do so)

If I install Atom from the .deb package on their website the fonts do go back to normal, but of course that way I won't get the commodity of automatic updates.

Brackets on the other hand does not install from the website-provided deb package, so I'm unsure on what to do there.

Here's how the programs look:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atom is not in the official repositories, so I assume you're installing it from a PPA. As [the unofficial Atom PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/atom) does not provide a version for Cosmic (18.10), you're probably installing the Bionic (18.04) package, so it's most likely a compatibility issue. I compared the dependencies between the PPA package and the downloadable DEB (`dpkg -I filename.deb`), and the former has GTK2 UI dependencies which are being dropped in favor of GTK3.

For now it's best you use the downloadable version, until (hopefully) that or another PPA starts providing a proper Cosmic version. Don't forget to check your [software sources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Other_Software_Tab) so that they're requesting a Cosmic version from the PPA instead of Bionic.

Brackets has similar GTK2 and other aged dependencies, so it may be very hard if not impossible to get it working properly on Ubuntu 18.10 until they modernize their code.

```
PPA (atom_1.26.1-1~webupd8~0_amd64.deb):  
Depends: git, gconf2, gconf-service, libgtk2.0-0, libudev0 | libudev1, 
         libgcrypt11 | libgcrypt20, libnotify4, libxtst6, libnss3, python, 
         gvfs-bin, xdg-utils, libdbus-1-3, libcap2, libxkbfile1, libx11-6, 
         libasound2, libsecret-1-0, gir1.2-secret-1

DEB (atom-amd64.deb):  
Depends: git, gconf2, gconf-service, libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10), libudev0 | libudev1, 
         libgcrypt11 | libgcrypt20, libnotify4, libxtst6, libnss3 (>= 2:3.22), 
         python, gvfs-bin, xdg-utils, libcap2, libx11-xcb1, libxss1, 
         libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libxkbfile1
```

Comment: I'm glad to know that there's not something wrong with my system, thank you for the great response. Also Atom is most definitely part of the repositories, I downloaded it from the Ubuntu Software program.

Comment: After a PPA source has been added, every APT package tool, including the Ubuntu Software Center lists software from those, too. The "Other software" tab in Software & Updates tool has a list of additional sources (usually PPA). I don't have 18.10 running on any of my devices because I usually stick to LTS releases to avoid issues like yours, but according to [the repository search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=atom) Atom is not in the official repositories.